# Hazelcast issue - who to get (listen) running application number

Tags: tomcat, hazelcast

I would like to learn whether it is possible to get or listen running applications "number" which are running on the pool IP that hazelcast is configured (distributed) for.

I am aware of the application logs that shows which ip is get in the pool right that moment or leave the pool (when that server is down). However, I could not find how to get this running instance numbers at runtime with hazelcast.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Hazelcast.getCluster().getMembers()
```

will give you the list of members. You can also addListener to listen the membership events via

```
Hazelcast.getCluster().addMembershipListener()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your req at first. Moreover, I would like to learn how to execute the second task you shared. I mean, should it be in a listener class or whatelse? Cant i import adding the cluster to membership listener in any configuration xml file? Because I actually dont know how to add this to listener when the server is being started.

Comment: You should implement com.hazelcast.core.MembershipListener and register an instance of that listener using Hazelcast.getCluster().addMembershipListener(membershipListener). Registering a listener in configuration xml will be available by version 2.0 which will be released in a month.